# Power of maximal ideal in the localization of $k[x,y]$ at $(x,y)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, let $R_p$ be the localization of $R=k[x,y]$ at the maximal ideal $p:=(x,y)$, i.e. $R_p:=\{F/G \in k(x,y) : g(0,0)\ne 0\}$. Then $R_p$ is a local ring with $m_p=\{f/g \in R_p : f(0,0)=0\}$ the unique maximal ideal. Now let $f,g\in k[x,y]$ be relatively prime, then $(f,g)_p $ is contained in $m_p$. My question:

> Is it true that $\exists d>0$ such that $m_p^d \subseteq (f,g)_p$ ?

I think this is related with [$k$ a field, $f,g$ be relatively prime polynomials in $k[x,y]$. Is every prime ideal of $k[x,y]$ containing $f$ and $g$ maximal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1995972/k-a-field-f-g-be-relatively-prime-polynomials-in-kx-y-is-every-prime-i), but I can't figure out anything. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's true. The images of $f,g$ in $R_p$ form a regular sequence, hence a system of parameters (recall that $\dim R_p=2$). This means that $(f,g)_p$ is $m_p$-primary. (The condition "algebraically closed" is superfluous.)

Comment: Of course they are related: in fact, the height of the ideal $(f,g)$ is two, and this remark solves both questions.