# A certain ideal of $k[x,y]$ containing $f(x) \in k[x], g(y) \in k[y]$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero (for example, $k= \mathbb{C}$),
and let $f(x) \in k[x]$ and $g(y) \in k[y]$ with $\deg_x(f(x)) \geq 1$ and $\deg_y(g(y)) \geq 1$.

Let $p,q \in k[x,y]$, and denote by $I$ the ideal generated by $\{p,q\}$,
$I:=\langle p,q \rangle$.

Further assume that $\{p,q\}$ are of the following forms:
$p= f_1+g_1+xy H_1$ and $q= f_2+g_2 +xy H_2$,
where $f_1,f_2 \in k[x]$, $g_1,g_2 \in k[y]$, $H_1,H_2 \in k[x,y]$
with $\langle f_1,f_2 \rangle =1$ and $\langle g_1,g_2 \rangle =1$.

> If it happens that $f(x),g(y) \in I$, does this imply something interesting about $p$ and $q$?

In other words: $f(x) \in I$ means that there exist $A,B \in k[x,y]$ such that
$f(x)=Ap+Bq$ and $g(y) \in I$ means that there exist $C,D \in k[x,y]$ such that
$g(y)=Cp+Dq$.

A somewhat relevant question is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1995972/k-a-field-f-g-be-relatively-prime-polynomials-in-kx-y-is-every-prime-i), but notice that here I do not assume that $I$ is a prime ideal (and $\{f(x),g(y)\}$ are not relatively prime).

Any hints and comments are welcome! Thank you.